# rename fastq file headers using sed command

Tags: sed, fastq

I am trying to rename the fastq header and add "/1" at the end of fastq header using sed commmand.
Here is my code:

```
sed i '1~4 s/$/\\1/g' seq/*_1.fq
```

But no change has been made. Does someone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @Christina - if the system lets you, please "upvote" and "accept" Allan Wind's reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add /1 to line n * 4 + 1 where n >= 0 for the files matching the glob seq/*_1.fq:

```
sed -i '1~4s/$/\/1/' seq/*_1.fq
```

You did not provide any input to here is what I used:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

and the result was:

```
a/1
b
c
d
e/1
f
```